discordjs - force fetch an user with user handle?
I'd like to force fetch an user, but with the handle and not the user id.
Is it possible?
Also note that the users I'm trying to fetch may not share a guild with my bot.
Here's what I'm trying to do:
const user = await client.users.fetch("USERNAME", { force: true, cache: true })
Maybe it's not possible because of discord's user hashing methods?

UserManager#fetch() parameters are (user: UserResolvable, options?: BaseFetchOptions) : Promise<User> where UserResolvable must be of type User | Snowflake | Message | GuildMember | ThreadMember. You cannot directly fetch a user with their username.
Without the user sharing a guild with the client, and without knowing the user id, you cannot fetch the user.
If it's possible the user is in a shared guild, check the cache:
const TARGET_USERNAME = "...";
const cachedUsers = client.users.cache;
const targetUser = cachedUsers.find(u => u.username == TARGET_USER);

let forceFetchedUser;

if (targetUser) {
   forceFetchedUser = await client.users.fetch(targetUser.id, { force: true });
} else {
   console.error("User not found");
}

If your client is in a small amount of servers with a moderate amount of total users, you may consider fetching all members of all guilds first:
// await client.guilds.fetch() - Fetch all guilds if necessary

for await (const guild of client.guilds.cache.values()) {
   await guild.members.fetch()
}

